# How can I check with SQL if a column contains a comma seperated list / string?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, explode

How can I check with SQL if a column contains a comma seperated list / string?

My query looks like this:

```
$modulare = $this->Database->prepare("
    SELECT id, titel, sorting, kuerzel
    FROM cc_produkte
    WHERE veroeffentlichen = 1
    AND kuerzel = ? // Here commas have to be filtered
    ORDER BY sorting, id ASC
")
->execute($pid);
```

The "kuerzel" column contains the shortcuts of individual products as a comma-separated string. But there are also products that have only a shortcut. Only one of the entries should be read. Unfortunately I can not do anything with the linked post.

Is there a possibility in SQL for this? For example, how does the explode function of PHP?

Comment: tbh I'd redesign the database **not** to have that type of data in :|

Comment: Storing CSV in a column defeats the purpose of a database.

Comment: The other comment was just removed, but useful if you really just want to check for comma. If you don't care about the values, use `kuerzel LIKE '%,%'`. No need for exploding then.

Comment: The "kuerzel" column contains the shortcuts of individual products as a comma-separated string. But there are also products that have only a shortcut. Only one of the entries should be read. Unfortunately I can not do anything with the linked post.

Comment: @MalteHartwig With LIKE %,% it works, thanks!

Comment: What they are implying is to use the strength of a relational database, and join to another table to get the "kuerzel" data

Comment: @Scuzzy 
It is already set up a complex database structure. However, I needed this query for a detached solution.